# How to unwrap a key using RSA in Bouncy castle c#?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

How do I unwrap a key using RSA private key in Bouncy castle? I receive the already wrapped key which was wrapped using the RSA public key. I have the RSA key pair. I just cannot find the api in the C# Bouncy Castle that I can use to unwrap it.

This code in the C# source code (https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp) is currently commented out. The commented out lines for the RSA is exactly what I need, but when I try to use them it seems that its been removed or never implemented

```
Key key = cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "RSA", IBufferedCipher.PRIVATE_KEY);
```

The line above is exactly what I need. Why has it been commented out? The full function in WrapTest.cs is given below:

```
public ITestResult Perform()
{
    try
        {
//              IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            IWrapper cipher = WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

            IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator fact = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("RSA");
            fact.Init(
                new RsaKeyGenerationParameters(
                    BigInteger.ValueOf(0x10001),
                    new SecureRandom(),
                    512,
                    25));

            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = fact.GenerateKeyPair();

            AsymmetricKeyParameter priKey = keyPair.Private;
            AsymmetricKeyParameter pubKey = keyPair.Public;

            byte[] priKeyBytes = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(priKey).GetDerEncoded();

            CipherKeyGenerator keyGen = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyGenerator("DES");

//              Key wrapKey = keyGen.generateKey();
            byte[] wrapKeyBytes = keyGen.GenerateKey();
            KeyParameter wrapKey = new DesParameters(wrapKeyBytes);

//              cipher.Init(IBufferedCipher.WRAP_MODE, wrapKey);
            cipher.Init(true, wrapKey);
//              byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.Wrap(priKey);
            byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.Wrap(priKeyBytes, 0, priKeyBytes.Length);

//              cipher.Init(IBufferedCipher.UNWRAP_MODE, wrapKey);
            cipher.Init(false, wrapKey);

//              Key key = cipher.unwrap(wrappedKey, "RSA", IBufferedCipher.PRIVATE_KEY);
            byte[] unwrapped = cipher.Unwrap(wrappedKey, 0, wrappedKey.Length);

            //if (!Arrays.AreEqual(priKey.getEncoded(), key.getEncoded()))
            if (!Arrays.AreEqual(priKeyBytes, unwrapped))
            {
                return new SimpleTestResult(false, "Unwrapped key does not match");
            }

            return new SimpleTestResult(true, Name + ": Okay");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new SimpleTestResult(false, Name + ": exception - " + e.ToString());
        }

}
```

Comment: You're talking about Java, right? Where exactly is this code commented out and why do you depend on it? You could just use it in your code.

Comment: Could you please include more code? Currently we don't even know the type of the `cipher` variable. @ArtjomB. well, there is `IBufferedCipher` in there, that feels a bit C#-ish.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have updated the question with a better explanation and more code.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Its the Bouncy Castle implementation in C#

Comment: The `unwrap` method was specified in lowercase, which either indicates that either there was an issue copying the code or that it was copied from Java. That will probably explain the confusion. **We don't know** why it was commented out (my Crystal Ball broke down with the destruction of Sauron); does it fail when you try to run it? **Where are you stuck?**

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I see. Maybe the code hasnt been ported over to C# yet, as it fails to find it when I try to use it. In that case I am left with just the C# libraries, and even there I dont see any way to wrap/unwrap using RSA. My issue is that I need to unwrap using a private RSA key

Comment: So, `cipher.Unwrap` in above code doesn't compile? Have you tried to simply decrypt? Wrapping *can* be different from encryption but for RSA it is usually the same operation. The only thing is that wrap / unwrap usually return a key *reference* while decrypt directly returns the key data. That is a problem when secure memory or hardware based crypto is used (e.g. TSM, HSM, Smart Card) but it isn't for an all-software library such as Bouncy Castle.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The Unwrap doesnt have an string parameter for "RSA". Also IBufferedCipher doesnt have a private key, so yes it doesnt compile. I understand what you are saying about the encrypt vs wrap. Problem is that I am working with an HSM where I need to extract a key and the only way the HSM will give the key is if it is wrapped with a key. Thus when I get it out I need to unwrap it. I have been considering writing a java exe that just unwraps and returns the result, but that is very much a hack

Comment: If you are trying to use the BC libraries to perform a wrap / unwrap in a HSM then you're taking the wrong route. BC is software only when it comes to the implementation of cryptographic algorithms *including wrapping / unwrapping*.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thats right, for my business case I need to get into software the key generated in the HSM. So the HSM wraps, and I need to unwrap in software, because unwrapping in HSM saves the key back to the HSM. Do you by any chance know of any C# libraries that can unwrap using RSA?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151295/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-and-minime).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on what you need, but you can use RSA keys to wrap and unwrap AES keys in Bouncycastle. Here is a Java example that creates an RSA keypair, saves the private key to a file, and then saves an AES key that has been wrapped in the public key.

```java
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Main {

    private static final SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024, rand);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        // Write out private key to file, PKCS8-encoded DER
        Files.write(Paths.get("privkey.der"), kp.getPrivate().getEncoded());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        kg.init(256, rand);
        SecretKey aesKey = kg.generateKey();

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
        c.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, kp.getPublic(), rand);
        byte[] wrappedKey = c.wrap(aesKey);

        // Write out wrapped key
        Files.write(Paths.get("wrappedkey"), wrappedKey);
    }
}
```

And here is a C# example that consumes the output from the Java example and unwraps the AES key.

```cs
using System.IO;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

namespace RSADecryptWithBouncy
{
    class MainClass
    {

        private static KeyParameter Unwrap(byte [] key, AsymmetricKeyParameter privKeyParam) {
            var wrapper = WrapperUtilities.GetWrapper("RSA/NONE/PKCS1PADDING");
            wrapper.Init(false, privKeyParam);
            var aesKeyBytes = wrapper.Unwrap(key, 0, key.Length);
            return new KeyParameter(aesKeyBytes);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var privKeyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("../../privkey.der");
            var seq = Asn1Sequence.GetInstance(privKeyBytes);
            var rsaKeyParams = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(PrivateKeyInfo.GetInstance(seq));
            var wrappedKey = File.ReadAllBytes("../../wrappedKey");
            var aesKey2 = Unwrap(wrappedKey, rsaKeyParams);
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: The problem, as I understand it, is that this needs to be in C# where the special wrap modes are missing.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I am fixing up my tests to make sure everything else works as expected, so that when I have the fix, I can verify correctly. Once the tests are done, I will try @MaartenBodewes suggestion to try encrypt and unwrap which for AES should be fine.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I will try that out

Comment: OK, cool. Now here's to hoping that PKCS#1 v1.5 padding was used and that the wrapped AES key is just some bytes instead of some kind of PKCS#11 template thingy.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes:  Thanks. As a troubling aside, when I replaced "PKCS1PADDING" with "OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding" the Bouncy C# code threw a "data hash wrong" exception.